# Three div / two column layout - possible with Flexbox?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I've been trying to achieve the layout below using flexbox. I originally had a left hand sidebar containing the image & navigation, and a main content area. On mobile, the sidebar used to wrap under the main content.

The problem with that is that I need the image to remain at the top on mobile, so I've been trying with three sibling `div`s in one wrapper `div`.

Is this even possible with flexbox or will I need to use css grid?

[image]

Comment: possible with flexbox: yes but it's more suitable with CSS grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although CSS Grid would be the best approach to achieve the lay-out you want, it is possible using CSS Flexbox.

You just have to create a wrapper `div` with three `div`s inside (when doing a *mobile first* approach) and with `.content` set to `flex: 1` to stretch out the height of your viewport.

Then for desktop (in this case `@media screen and (min-width: 1000px)`), change the order ([MDN reference of `order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)) of `.navigation` and `.content` and give all three `div`s appropriate widths according to their needs. The only change to `div.wrapper` is that it needs `flex-flow: column wrap` to wrap correctly.

[image: Screen resize of desktop to mobile]

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-flow: column wrap;
  }
  
  .navigation {
    order: 2;
  }
  
  .content {
    order: 3;
  }
  
  .image,
  .navigation {
    width: 200px;
    flex: 50%;
  }
  
  .content {
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
}


/* Generic styling */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.image {
  background: orange;
  height: 60px;
}

.content {
  background: lightblue;
}

.navigation {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box image">Image</div>
  <div class="box content">Content</div>
  <div class="box navigation">Navigation</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Genius, I will give this a go.

Comment: @ChrisJAllen Did it work out for you?

Comment: yes it sure did. Thanks a lot. I can now replace the bodged showing and hiding of duplicate images and adapt this to work.